# Remove user from Firebase Auth

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using the email/password auth from firebase to manage authentication to my angular application. I have created an admin panel to manage the users which based on CRUD to control the users on the app.

So far I have managed to create new users and user their localID to store additional information about that user such as name, age etc. in a real time database

The issue I have run into is when looking at the documentation for the firebase auth api (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-create-email-password) it refers to using the IdToken which is created when the current user if logged in. I want to be able to edit/delete a different user to the one that is currently logged in but I am unable to find anything in the documentation relating to this?

Any help is much appreciated if I am looking in the wrong place or any work around if not possible?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be impossible to delete a user different from the currently logged in user from the client-side. Wouldn't it be dangerous otherwise?

What you could do instead:

- create a Cloud Function, callable from client side,
- within this function, check for permission,
- and then delete the user using the admin SDK

```
exports.deleteUser = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const uidToDelete = data.uidToDelete;
  const uid = context.auth.uid;

  if(!canDelete(uid, uidToDelete))
    return "forbidden";  

  await admin.auth().deleteUser(uidToDelete);

  return "done";
});
```

This is described in the [guides](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user) and in the [reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth-1#deleteuser).

Comment: Shame, don't understand how they couldn't implement a way to do this since it would be a trusted users that would be logged in that would be managing the account. Thanks anyway

Comment: To enforce only trusted users can delete other users, we need a way to check permission, either with function code, or it could be with security rules for auth specially dedicated for this use case. Would you prefer writing security rules rather than a function?

Comment: I could try the SDK, but haven't had any experience with using one before. Just a shame that the REST api only has half the features although i'm using the firebase auth to control access anyway