# how to delete a user account using pyrebase?

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, flask, pyrebase

I am building a flask app that creates user accounts in `firebase auth` using `pyrebase`.

```py
@app.route('/verify_email')
def verify_email(self):
    end = time.time()
    start = self.start
    if end-start > 1800:
        # delete user
    else:
        return render_template('email_verification.html')
```

here I am deleting any user that doesn't verify email under 30 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this in an older version of the README:

```
auth = firebase.auth()
user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)
auth.delete_user_account(user['idToken'])
```

Comment: We need password to delete? Can we delete without password as we already have the permission after calling `firebase.auth()`? I found using firebase-admin can delete without password here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64865342/248616

Answer (score 0):

**Do not use pyrebase**

```
pip install pyrebase
```

**instead use pyrebase4**

```
pip install pyrebase4
```

as @Nathan mentioned use `delete_user_account` method.

Comment: Hey there! Please tell the asker why they should not use pyrebase! Thanks for your answer.